# How to write a combination Seasonal ARIMA model in mathematical form

Tags: arima, sas, seasonality, moving-average

I'm doing a forecast combination model in SAS: the first is an ARIMA (10, 0, 1)(0,1,1)s NOINT with a point intervention at t=3

And the second is a MA model with only lag 13 and simple differencing d = 1 also with a point intervention at t=3. MA(q=13) NOINT. I did this in Factored ARIMA.

What is the equation of the model in terms of the original variable $y_t$? Please show steps how to solve it.

This is very new to me so any help is appreciated!

By the way, the forecast combination model was created with fit regression weights: and has weight = 0.8637 for the first model and weight = 0.1352 for the second model.